# Upload file in SharePoint using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sharepoint, file-upload

'm trying to upload a file using Python Script, when Run the code it gives me no Error but was not able to upload the file in my sharepoint folder.

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365
from config import config

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']
site_name = config['sp_site_name']
base_path = config['sp_base_path']
doc_library = config['sp_doc_library']

file_name = "cat_pic.jpg"

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})


# perform the actual upload
with open( file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
    try: 
        response = session.post( 
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
    except Exception as err: 
        print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

```
config.py

config = dict()
config['sp_user'] = 'email'
config['sp_password'] = 'pass
config['sp_base_path'] = 'https://bboxxeng.sharepoint.com'
config['sp_site_name'] = 'TESTIAN'
config['sp_doc_library'] = 'Test'
```

This is the url of my sharepoint https://bboxxeng.sharepoint.com/sites/TESTIAN/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx I've already created a folder in it named Test...

Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Can you share the exact error you are getting

Comment: Hi @CalebNjiiri, There's no error showing after running the script. 
But when I check my Sharepoint folder the uploaded file was not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the code as below.

```
response = session.post( 
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/"+doc_library+"')/Files/add(url='" 
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
```

Comment: Thank you, It solves by editing my config file and changing the doc_library to `Shared%20Documents/Test`

Comment: Glad to hear that you solve this issue,thanks for your sharing. If my reply helps you, you can mark the reply as answer, it will make others who stuck with the similar issue easier to search for valid solutions in this forum.