# Python upload files and folder to sharepoint

Tags: python-3.x, file, sharepoint, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some files (multiple files and folder) to sharepoint and when I run the script i dont have any errors but i'm unable so see my files in sharepoint.

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365

# get data from configuration
username = 'last.surname@tenant.com'
password = 'mypassword'
site_name = 'BI_odair'
base_path = 'https://tenant.sharepoint.com'
doc_library = 'data'

file_name = "links.txt"

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username,
                       password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})


# perform the actual upload
with open(file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
    try:
        response = session.post(
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name +
            "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/" +
            doc_library+"')/Files/add(url='"
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))
```

URL for my sharepoint: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/BI_odair/Documents%20partages/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewid=4e7fdfb9%2De84a%2D42cd%2Db537%2D0d2837ca92cc
Theres already a folder named Data, but i wanted to upload my files in the root folder "/Documents%20partages"

I've already added this to my code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59083429/6754555

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution that worked perfectly on my end:

`pip install SharePlum` and then use the code below

```
import requests
from shareplum import Office365

# Set Login Info
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
site_name = '<site_name>'
base_path = 'https://<domain_name>.sharepoint.com'
doc_library = 'Shared%20Documents'
nested_folder = 'Shared%20Documents/<folder1>/<folder2>' #if you want to upload in nested folders else nested_folder = doc_library
file_name = "my_file.zip" #when your file in the same directory

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})
response = session.post(url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                         data="")
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

# perform the actual upload
with open(file_name, 'rb') as file_input:
    try:
        response = session.post(
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + f"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + nested_folder + "')/Files/add(url='"
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",

            data=file_input)
        print("response: ", response.status_code) #it returns 200
        if response.status_code == '200':
            print("File uploaded successfully")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Something went wrong: " + str(err))

print('File Uploaded Successfully')
```

Answer (score 1):

"Shared Documents" is the default document library. If you want to upload file to a custom library, please modify the path as below:

```
response = session.post(
        url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name +
        "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Documents%20partages")/Files/add(url='"
        + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
        data=file_input)
```

Also you can have a look at below blog:[Uploading files to SharePoint](https://www.pythonbite.tech/11-blog/python-advanced/4-uploading-files-to-sharepoint)

////////  Updated

I created a document library and tested the demo in above blog, it works well.
[image]

Below is my code:

```html
import requests
from shareplum import Office365
from config import config

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']
site_name = config['sp_site_name']
base_path = config['sp_base_path']
doc_library = config['sp_doc_library']

file_name = "test.csv"

# Obtain auth cookie
authcookie = Office365(base_path, username=username, password=password).GetCookies()
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = authcookie
session.headers.update({'user-agent': 'python_bite/v1'})
session.headers.update({'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'})

# dirty workaround.... I'm getting the X-RequestDigest from the first failed call
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': 'FormDigestValue'})
response = session.post( url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='a.txt',overwrite=true)",
                         data="")
session.headers.update({'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})

# perform the actual upload
with open( r'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.csv', 'rb+') as file_input:
    try: 
        response = session.post( 
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + doc_library + "')/Files/add(url='" 
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
    except Exception as err: 
        print("Some error occurred: " + str(err))

print('end...')
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the code and i doen't work either! and when i print the response i get the error 403. Here's the root folder: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/BI_odair/Documents%20partages/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: `response = session.post(
            url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name +
            "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("'Documents%20partages'")/Files/add(url='"
            + file_name + "',overwrite=true)",
            data=file_input)
        print("response: ", response)`

Comment: it seems that the url string is not be joined correctly. please have a try below url=base_path + "/sites/" + site_name +
        "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents%20partages')/Files/add(url='"
        + file_name + "',overwrite=true)"

Comment: When i run the script and print the response i get this: `response:  <Response [404]> `

Comment: Updated the reply

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spupload.py", line 26, in <module>
    {'X-RequestDigest': response.headers['X-RequestDigest']})
  File "C:\Users\odavaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'x-requestdigest'`